# Checking value against an array issue

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This is killing me. It seems so simple, but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

Basically what I have is a function that accepts a single string `$name` as a variable, then it goes through and checks that variable against values in an array. If the variable is found in the array is returns `TRUE`. This function is called from within a foreach loop in another function (which submits a new `$name` variable each time.)

I have tried 3 different ways to check the variable against the array but it never works properly.

**1.)** using another `foreach()` loop

```
function check($name) {

$commaSeparatedString = 'First Name, Second Name, Third Name';
$array = explode(",", $commaSeparatedString);

foreach($array as $arrayValue) {
if($arrayValue == $name) { 
return TRUE; 
}
else {
return FALSE; 
}
}
}
```

**2.)** using `in_array()`

```
function check($name) {
  $commaSeparatedString = 'First Name, Second Name, Third Name';
  $array = explode(",", $commaSeparatedString);

    if(in_array($name, $array, TRUE)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**3.)** looping through each value in the array manually and checking for a match

```
function check($name) {
$commaSeparatedString = 'First Name, Second Name, Third Name';
$array = explode(",", $commaSeparatedString);
$count = count($array);
$i = 0; 
while($i<=$count) {
  if(isset($array[$i]) && $array[$i] == $name) {
      $i++;
      echo $i;
      return TRUE;
              break;

      }
  else { 
  $i++;
  echo $i;
  return FALSE; }
}

}
```

Here a simplified part of the function where `check()` is run:

```
function loopCheck() {
$group = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3, $obj4, $obj5);
foreach($group as $groupValue) {
  $name = $groupValue->name; 
  $ignore = $this->check($name);
  if($ignore == TRUE) { }
  else { echo $name; }
}
}
```

The result for all three variations of `check()` is the same. It returns `TRUE` for every `$groupValue` except the first value of `$array`. So if the `$name` of `$obj2` was 'First Name' it would return `TRUE`, but if the `$name` of `$obj3` was 'Second Name' is still returns `FALSE`. I echoed `$i` for the third variation at one point and the value consistently stayed at 1, so I know there is some error with that method, but I don't know why the result would be the same using the other 2 methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. The one that causes the failure of all code, is that you `explode` by `','`, thus leaving a whitespace in your strings. You should `explode` on `', '`.

But the first code is erroneous still: The `foreach` will return on the first iteration, always, thus checking only the first element. The loop should be:

```
foreach ($array as $arrayValue) {
    if ($arrayValue == $name) { 
        return true; 
    }
}

return false;
```

Same applies to your last code.

The best variant is probably the second, here is a slightly shorter, adjusted variant:

```
function check($name) {
    $commaSeparatedString = 'First Name, Second Name, Third Name';

    return in_array($name, explode(', ', $commaSeparatedString), true));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am a beginner when it comes to PHP, so my code is long and redundant to help me understand what the code is doing better. This solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

Did you trim() your strings?

It would work on the first string as it starts with "First String" but the second explode()ed string would be "spaceSecond String".

Comment: I did not know of the trim() method, and added it to the check() function using a foreach loop on the $array. However, nothing changed. I echoed the $trimmed variable from within the foreach loop and it only output the first value in the array.

Comment: Any difference in the casing?
That is, are you comparing "First String" to "first string" ?

Comment: You are right. I did need to trim the exploded values, but I needed to move my `return False;` declaration out of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put

```
Return false;
```

On your else, you should put it after the whole loop.
Also keep in mind that if you wanna explode **a, b, c** to be [a,b,c] you have to use

```
explode(", ",$str); //note the space
```

Answer (score 1):

I think any of those techniques will work, but you just have small errors.

I've fixed the first one below.  You don't want to `return false` in an else clause.  you want it AFTER the foreach loop, only if it fails to match EVERY time.

```
function check($name) {

$commaSeparatedString = 'First Name, Second Name, Third Name';
$array = explode(",", $commaSeparatedString);

foreach($array as $arrayValue) {
    if($arrayValue == $name) { 
        return TRUE; 
    }
}
 return false;
}
```

The in_array version is potentially simpler.  Notice that there is no reason for `if ($val) {return true;} else {return false;}`, just do `return $val`

```
function check($name)
{
    $csvs = 'First Name, Second Name, Third Name';
    return in_array($name, explode(', ', $csv));
    //return in_array(trim(strtoupper($name)), array_map('trim', explode(', ', strtoupper($csv))));
    //try this second way is kind of over-kill thorough, but try it if you still get false where true is expected
}
```

You also have to either `trim` the strings of the array you make or `explode(', ' $csv)` with a space.  Otherwise the elements of `array` will have a leading space.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that  when you make the explode in the check function, some pieces have spaces because there is a space after the comma.